# Adding TEXT parameters to ADODB.Command without using stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, parameters, adodb

I need to perform `INSERT`s on a SQL Server 2008 table with some `TEXT` columns, and I can't have the `ADODB.Command` parameter for the `TEXT` column working.

The table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (
    TestId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , CreationDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    , Value TEXT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT pkTest PRIMARY KEY (TestId)
)
```

The test page is like this:

```
<!-- METADATA TYPE="typelib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" VERSION="2.8" -->
<%@ CODEPAGE = 65001 LCID = 1040 %>
<%
    Option Explicit
    Response.Clear
    Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
    Response.CodePage = 65001
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Dim i : i = 0
    Dim value : value = ""
    For i = 1 To 10000
        If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            value = value & "a "
        Else
            value = value & "a"
        End If
    Next
    Dim connection : Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connection.CommandTimeout = 5
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=XXX; Database=XXX; Uid=XXX; Pwd=XXX;"
    connection.ConnectionTimeout = 5
    connection.IsolationLevel = adXactReadUncommitted
    connection.Mode = adModeRead
    connection.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
    connection.Open
    Dim command : Set command = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    command.ActiveConnection = connection
    command.CommandText = "insert into dbo.Test (CreationDate, Value) values (getdate(), ?)"
    command.CommandTimeout = 5
    command.CommandType = adCmdText
    command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter("Value", adVarChar, adParamInput, 0, value)
    command.Prepared = True
    command.Execute
    Set command = Nothing
    connection.Close
    Set connection = Nothing
    Response.End
%>
```

When I execute it, I get this error:

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0d5d'
Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.
/test/default.asp, line 32
```

Line 32 is

```
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter("Value", adVarChar, adParamInput, 0, value)
```

I tried changing the Size parameter, to no avail.

Looking around the net I found the Microsoft Knowledge Base Article called [How to call SQL Server stored procedures from ASP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164485/), its "Method 1" example is interesting, as it does not declares the parameters but reads them form the server:

```
cmd.CommandText = "sp_test"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters(1) = 11
```

so I created a stored procedure to perform the `INSERT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestInsertion (@CreationDate DATETIME, @Value TEXT) AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test (CreationDate, Value) VALUES (@CreationDate, @Value)
    SELECT TestId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

and modified the `ADODB.Command` bit in the page like this:

```
Dim command : Set command = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
command.ActiveConnection = connection
command.CommandText = "dbo.TestInsertion"
command.CommandTimeout = 5
command.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
command.Parameters.Refresh
command.Parameters(1).Value = Date
command.Parameters(2).Value = value
command.Prepared = True
command.Execute
Set command = Nothing
```

and it worked.

Is it possible to specify a `TEXT` parameter for `ADODB.Command`s in classic ASP without resorting to stored procedures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to pass `adLongVarChar` constant for the **text** data type.

With `adLongVarChar` you also need to specify the size of `value`, otherwise you will get the `Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.` error.

```
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter("Value", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(value), value)
```

See some [ADO Data Type Mappings](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp).

Comment: Excellent, `adLongVarChar` works; however I must specify the parameter's length, otherwise I get the `Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.` error. I've updated your answer accordingly.